# How can I give an array of objects a variety of colors?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, workflow

I would like to give the objects in an array (using array modifier) different colors.  Right now the array of objects is just one color, and i would like to give each member of the array a different color, using a gradient.  Is this possible?  I have tried using the Particle Info node to no avail.

Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

I think you need to *apply* your [array modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/array.html#array-modifier), and then [separate](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/separate.html?#separate) by loose parts in *edit mode*.  Press <kbd>P</kbd>*>loose parts* to do this.

Add an [*object info*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/object_info.html#inputs) node to your material, and use the *random output*. This will assign each object assigned the material a color from the gradient.

A basic setup would look something like this:
[image]

This is an example of the effect with an arrayed Suzanne with setup shown:

[image]

Answer (score 15):

Use "Object" from "Texture coordinate" input node (without applying the arrays).

[image]

The object output is relative to "position coordinate in the object space" (see the [documentation](https://www.blender.org/manual/fr/render/cycles/nodes/input.html)).

[image]

From that you can separate the coordinate in X, Y, Z and use these inputs as R G B channels.

In the exemple below, I used a multiply but you can choose the way you want (color ramp, ...).

After that, recompose all in a "combine RGB" node as color input for your shader.

[image]

As you can see, the result is very bright : this is because the values are above 1. The value input node is here to modulate theses values, in order to obtain the intensity you want.

Comment: Vector and Color types are identical (XYZ => RGB) and thus can be plugged into each others' sockets without a problem.  So a simpler but equivalent setup would be to plug the Value into a color multiply node.

Comment: thanks for this very useful answer that provides a solution that doesn't require applying the array! It took me a while to get it to work, because my array went in negative X direction instead of positive and I didn't realise it. I just thought I mention this, in case anyone else is struggling. Because some colour inputs don't like minus signs! After I figured this out it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You can assign different materials to the faces of each object in the array, and that will allow you to apply different textures as well, without having to separate the array first.

Just go into Edit mode. select the faces you want to assign a specific color to, add a new material, and then assign it while the faces are selected. Do this for each object in the array.

Comment: when I'm in edit mode I can only select the first element in edit mode and all changes I make are then applied to each element of the array. Can you specify how to select other elements in the arry?

Comment: Faces of individual objects in an array can be selected only after applying the array modifier. This is not the solution for the problem presented here.